# Pandas: to_datetime tuple header - then match closest

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a CSV (similar to the one below) that I'm trying to match a column based on two inputs, one of which will be an exact match, the other will be a "closest" as simple as less than or equal to.

DataFrame code:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# pseudo CSV data
x = StringIO('''
main,A,A,A,B,B,B
date,1/1/2016,3/1/2016,5/1/2016,1/1/2016,3/1/2016,5/1/2016
one,11,22,33,44,55,66
two,77,88,99,111,222,333
''')

df = pd.read_csv(x, header = [0,1], tupleize_cols = True)
```

Inputs will be something like:

```
my_main = 'B'
my_date = pd.to_datetime('2/1/2016')
```

And I'd like the return to be:

```
   (B, 1/1/2016)
0             44
1            111
```

This may also be a job for a MultiIndex - but I'm totally unfamiliar with that functionality.

I think one of the first steps would be to convert the second part of the tuple header `to_datetime()`, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

...obviously `df[('B','1/1/2016')]` would work, but it's the *closest* part that is the rub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to find the correct columns.

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2/1/2016')
df[[c for c in df if c[0] == 'B' and pd.to_datetime(c[1]) <= date]]

   (B, 1/1/2016)
0             44
1            111
```

Comment: Ok, so you're sticking with the tuple headers there.  This is a fantastic method, thank you!